# How to show a "temp" slide during bullets animation in keynote

Tags: keynote

Sorry if this question sounds stupid, but I haven't found any answer.

I know I can animate a bulleted-list in keynote so it **appears by bullet**, one by one. Can I insert a full-screen slide (picture or something) in the middle of this animation?

Like this.

1. Show bullet #1
2. Show bullet #2
3. Show a full-screen slide
4. Show bullet #3

The only solution I can think of - is to create two duplicate slides and a picture-slide in between.

PS. Adding "links" to other slide won't help since I only have a "next" button during the presentation, no mouse/kbd/touchscreen

Comment: I'm torn—creating duplicate slides means more text to update if you need to make changes, but putting everything on one slide (e.g. futzing with build order and build-in/build-out so the full-slide picture is on top of everything, but only when it should be shown) means the image covers everything while I'm editing slides.

Answer (score 1):

Make two text boxes, the first with bullets 1 and 2 and the second with bullet 3. Then add an entrance and exit effect for the picture in between the entrances of the two text boxes.